# Why is C4265 Visual C++ warning (virtual member function and no virtual destructor) off by default?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, destructor, compiler-warnings

Visual C++ can emit [C4265 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzxffy8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when a class has at least one virtual member function and no virtual destructor.

Obviously the warning is there to detect cases when a derived class object is `delete`d through a pointer to base class and there's no virtual destructor in the base class. Such situation yields undefined behavior. Btw I've just found an example of this situation in a rather huge codebase precisely by enabling C4265 in Visual C++.

And this warning is off by default.

Why? What would happen if I enabled it and added a virtual destructor to each class where the warning is emitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the documentation for that warning it explains Microsoft's reasoning. `If a warning is off by default, most users would not want to see it.`

Comment: Note a very common case where C4265 will trigger (if you have it enabled) is with implementing "interfaces" (i.e. abstract virtual classes) which do not have virtual dtors defined in them. A simple fix is to mark your class as ``final`` indicating that nobody is going to be deriving from your class so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that C4265 in Visual C++ is the same warning as ``-Wnon-virtual-dtor `` and/or ``-Wdelete-non-abstract-non-virtual-dtor `` in clang/LLVM.

Comment: They're not the same, actually.  Visual C++ (at least some versions) appears to warn in cases where a class has a non-virtual destructor, even if the destructor is protected or private.  By contrast clang won't complain if the destructor is protected or private.  The distinction is important; see http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-dtor-virtual

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that sometimes you don't need a virtual destructor, even if you do have virtual functions (and therefore think about inheriting from it).

You need a virtual destructor if you allocate memory in a derived class and need to free it on object destruction, but that's not always the case.

A virtual destructor also means you should implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator (the rule of three) which are also not needed if your class members are just POD types.

So to summarize: you would get this warning even for classes where you don't need the virtual destructor, so why have it?

Comment: I don't think the rule of three goes that way. An empty virtual destructor is enough for polymorphic delete. Is the very same destructor you already got (provided by the compiler), just `virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of warning can be among those who use the pattern Mixin classes.

WikiPedia: In object-oriented programming languages, a mixin is a class that provides a certain functionality to be inherited or just reused by a subclass, while not meant for instantiation (the generation of objects of that class). Mixins are synonymous with abstract base classes. Inheriting from a mixin is not a form of specialization but is rather a means of collecting functionality. A class or object may "inherit" most or all of its functionality from one or more mixins, therefore mixins can be thought of as a mechanism of multiple inheritance.

Example:

Mixed class

```
template <typename T> struct AddNoEq {
  virtual bool operator==(const T &cmp) const = 0;
  bool operator!=(const T &cmp) const {
    return !static_cast<const T*>(this)->operator== (cmp);
  }
};
```

Use:

```
struct Complex : public AddNoEq<Complex> {
  Complex(int re, int im): re_(re), im_(im) { }

  virtual bool operator==(const Complex& cmp) const {
      return cmp.re_ == this->re_ && cmp.im_ == this->im_;
  }
  // ...
private:
  int re_, im_;
};

int main()
{
  Complex a(1, 2), b(2, 3);

    if (a != b)
      std::cout << "OK!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Microsoft sometimes makes warning about "deprecated functions" that are not marked as such by the specification committee, or about certain "good or bad practice".

Having a non virtual destructor in an object that has virtual methods is a potential risk if that object is designed to leave in a polymorphic OOP environment (where `delete pObject` must properly also `delete pDerived`, even if viewed with `pObject`).
But this is just one of the paradigm C++ support... hence such a warning may be meaningless:

Also `p->dosomething()` doesn't call `Derived::dosomething` if `dosomething` isn't virtual, but no warning is generated for that.

To me `delete p`, pretending `P::~P()` to result in invoking `D::~D()` is not a special case, and should not deserve a warning.

But -unfortunately- OOP was the first paradigm C++ was initially supporting and the paradigm the most of programmers and circulating books and teachers refer to, so they deployed the best practice "don't derive if the destructor isn't virtual", unfortunately reported also by Scot Meyers in his "Effective C++", thus making it "popular" and continuously referred also if there is no technical reason for it to continue to exist.

Today is a non sense like the most of "don't do this, don't do that" (include the famous "goto considered harmful" by Dijkstra, that made a lot of new emphasis on structured programming but also many ridiculous ways to spin around just to avoid it. Ha ... Miscrosoft din't have a warning for the use of goto yet ...  May be Meyers is more influent than Djikstra was ??)

The only good practice is "don't do ANYTHING if you don't know what you're doing!".
Nothing prohibits to accept suggestion, but a "best practoce" is not an "always good practice" (otherwise it will not "best": will just be "only") and a compiler (as a formal tool) should not warn about subjective feelings.